# cc: error: this_example.o: No such file or directory

Tags: c, object, makefile

I've a SDK with some examples, but when I want to compile any of these examples, I receive this error:

```
cc -g -I -o this_example.o -c this_example.c
cc: error: this_example.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:15: this_example.o] Error 1
```

Here is the makefile:

```
CC ?= gcc
INC_PATH ?= $(realpath ../inc)
LIB_PATH ?= $(realpath ../lib)
LIBS ?= $(wildcard $(LIB_PATH)/*.a) -pthread -lrt -lm
LDFLAGS :=-g -L$(LIB_PATH)
CFLAGS +=-g -I$(INC_PATH)

EXAMPLES=sdk_this_example_folder

.PHONY: all

all: $(EXAMPLES)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

this_example: this_example.o  frozen.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS) -Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN/../../lib'

clean:
    rm -f *~ *.o $(EXAMPLES)
```

In this_example_folder, I've four files: Makefile, this_example.c and frozen.c and frozen.h. Where is the problem? Thank you everybody for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `realpath` function returns the empty string if the path you are expanding doesn't exist.

You have:

```
INC_PATH ?= $(realpath ../inc)
```

then:

```
CFLAGS +=-g -I$(INC_PATH)
```

and your command output is:

```
cc -g -I -o this_example.o -c this_example.c
```

Clearly, the value of `INC_PATH` is empty (since there's nothing after the `-I` in the command line) which  means the directory `../inc` does not exist.

As for why you get that failure: the `-I` option expects a filename afterwards.  Since you don't have one, it uses `-o` (the next word in the command line) as the filename.  That means that `this_example.o` is treated as a file to compile, rather than the output file, and of course it doesn't exist.